# ARC4 encryption not working correctly server side

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a socket.io client which sends data to each other where encryption is based on ARC4.

I tried multiple different scenarios but it keeps failing to decrypt anything and I'm not sure why.

The class: `ARC4_New`

```
    public class ARC4_New
    {
        private int i;
        private int j;
        private byte[] bytes;

        public const int POOLSIZE = 256;

        public ARC4_New()
        {
            bytes = new byte[POOLSIZE];
        }

        public ARC4_New(byte[] key)
        {
            bytes = new byte[POOLSIZE];
            this.Initialize(key);
        }

        public void Initialize(byte[] key)
        {
            this.i = 0;
            this.j = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < POOLSIZE; ++i)
            {
                this.bytes[i] = (byte)i;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < POOLSIZE; ++i)
            {
                j = (j + bytes[i] + key[i % key.Length]) & (POOLSIZE - 1);
                this.Swap(i, j);
            }

            this.i = 0;
            this.j = 0;
        }

        private void Swap(int a, int b)
        {
            byte t = this.bytes[a];
            this.bytes[a] = this.bytes[b];
            this.bytes[b] = t;
        }

        public byte Next()
        {
            this.i = ++this.i & (POOLSIZE - 1);
            this.j = (this.j + this.bytes[i]) & (POOLSIZE - 1);
            this.Swap(i, j);
            return this.bytes[(this.bytes[i] + this.bytes[j]) & 255];
        }

        public void Encrypt(ref byte[] src)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < src.Length; k++)
            {
                src[k] ^= this.Next();
            }
        }

        public void Decrypt(ref byte[] src)
        {
            this.Encrypt(ref src);
        }
    }

        public System.Numerics.BigInteger RandomInteger(int bitSize)
        {
            var integerData = new byte[bitSize / 8];
            _numberGenerator.NextBytes(integerData);

            integerData[integerData.Length - 1] &= 0x7f;
            return new System.Numerics.BigInteger(integerData);
        }
```

My script which generates a key:

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger DHPrivate = RandomInteger(256);
System.Numerics.BigInteger DHPrimal = RandomInteger(256);
System.Numerics.BigInteger DHGenerated = RandomInteger(256);
if (DHGenerated > DHPrimal)
{
     System.Numerics.BigInteger tempG = DHGenerated;
     DHGenerated= DHPrimal;
     DHPrimal = tempG;
}
```

Then with those values I generate a public key:

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger DHPublic = System.Numerics.BigInteger.ModPow(DHGenerated, DHPrivate, DHPrimal);
```

Then I encrypt this key:

```
string pkey = EncryptY(CalculatePublic, DHPublic);
```

(Additional code for the encryption below)

```
        protected virtual string EncryptY(Func<System.Numerics.BigInteger, System.Numerics.BigInteger> calculator, System.Numerics.BigInteger value)
        {
            byte[] valueData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value.ToString());
            valueData = PKCSPad(valueData);

            Array.Reverse(valueData);
            var paddedInteger = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(valueData);

            System.Numerics.BigInteger calculatedInteger = calculator(paddedInteger);
            byte[] paddedData = calculatedInteger.ToByteArray();
            Array.Reverse(paddedData);

            string encryptedValue = Utils.Converter.BytesToHexString(paddedData).ToLower();
            return encryptedValue.StartsWith("00") ? encryptedValue.Substring(2) : encryptedValue;
        }

        protected virtual byte[] PKCSPad(byte[] data)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[128 - 1];
            int dataStartPos = (buffer.Length - data.Length);

            buffer[0] = (byte)Padding;
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, buffer, dataStartPos, data.Length);

            int paddingEndPos = (dataStartPos - 1);
            bool isRandom = (Padding == PKCSPadding.RandomByte);
            for (int i = 1; i < paddingEndPos; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = (byte)(isRandom ?
                    _numberGenerator.Next(1, 256) : byte.MaxValue);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
```

After all that I sent the string `PKEY` to the server.

And after decrypting the string, the server gets the public key which is for example: 127458393

When I connect both my client and server using: 127458393

Like:

```
BigInteger key = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("127458393");
client = new ARC4_New(PrimalDing.ToByteArray());
```

My client sends a string like:

```
client.Encrypt(BYTE_HERE);
```

And my server reads it like:

```
client.Decrypt(BYTE_HERE);
```

But it fails, and gets a random unreadable string.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My geuss is that there is somthing wrong in the ARC4_NEW script but i'm not sure, this is the first time i dipped my toe in this style of code..

Comment: I recommend 1) using established cryptographic libraries like Bouncy Castle for this rather than ever rolling your own, even if you're implementing an existing algorithm (not only due to the possibility of obvious mistakes, but especially and also non-obvious ones that allow side-channel attacks) and 2) *not* using algorithms that have known vulnerabilities, which RC4 notoriously does. If you are stuck with a protocol because an implementation mandates it somewhere, consider using interop code to communicate with the native implementation. Slower, but still less hassle than reimplementing.

Comment: I'd verify that the byte arrays you're getting in Initialize are the same at both ends. And then that the bytes state is the same. I can't see anything obviously wrong; `++this.i` looks odd to me, I'd use `(this.i + 1)` just in case there's a strange misoptimization happening here but I doubt it. Is one end running as 32-bit and the other 64? I believe they optimize differently.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the reply, the problem is that i reverse engeneered the "server", so i can only modify the client. Both applications run 64bit by the way, forcing both in 32bit or 64bit sadly did not fix anything. The ting is there isn't an error in the code because the "closed source client" sends data and the server decrypts it fine. I use 100% the exact same ARC4 class as the server because that part is opensource but even on the client side, When i decrypt with: client.Encrypt and the client.Decrypt it doesn't return the same value as it was before encryption thats the main problem here.

Comment: It ought to? You'll need to make a new ARC4 for each of encryption and decryption: it's a stream cipher, so you'll need the streams in the same place - you can't just call client.Encrypt then client.Decrypt with the same client.

Comment: Would you mind providing a sample code of the ARC4 (preferably with the class i used above) @Rup ?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind on that i figured the encryption part out.

Comment: Glad you've got that working! Here's what I'd typed anyway: https://repl.it/@RupW/ARC4-class-example

Comment: I managed to fix the issue

For some reason, my server was and is reversing the bytes i used in the ARC4 client, besides that thankyou for the sample code i will defenetly keep that example :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue

For some reason, my server was and is reversing the bytes i used in the ARC4 client..

So i simple reverse it now as a hotfix

System.Numerics.BigInteger temp = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse(textBox1.Text);
client = new ARC4_New(temp.ToByteArray().Reverse().ToArray());